# sqlite3: conditional Insert in table using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert a value using following code

```
insert_query = """INSERT OR REPLACE INTO results
                          (output_text, processed) 
                           VALUES 
                          ('html', 1)
                          select  user_id, user_token FROM results
                          WHERE
                          user_id = usr_id AND user_token = usr_token"""
```

cur.execute(insert_query)

I am getting

> OperationalError: near "select": syntax error

`WHERE` can't be used with `INSERT` that's why I am using `SELECT` but still I am getting this error. Can someone help wit this issue? Thank you

Comment: This is not a valid SQL syntax. But as you did not describe precisely what you were trying to achieve I cannot give you the correct syntax. Probably `select  user_id, user_token FROM results` should not be there, but if `usr_id` and `usr_token` are Python variables, more must be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you having a look at the [sqlite syntax for insertion](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/).

To me it seems that for what you are trying to achieve, an [UPDATE statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm) would be more appropriate

Comment: Not necessarily. It looks like OP is trying to do [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `VALUES ('html', 1)` if you have a `SELECT`. You can't have `VALUES`  and a `SELECT` in the same `INSERT`. See [sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for more information.

This should work:

```
insert_query = """INSERT OR REPLACE INTO results
                          (output_text, processed) 
                          select  user_id, user_token FROM results
                          WHERE
                          user_id = usr_id AND user_token = usr_token"""
```